# Parsing json with different value type for the same key

Tags: flutter, dart

I know you can parse a json string then check if a value is of specific type. I wonder is there is a convention in Flutter to do that?

Example:

```
"{"id":1,"some_key":100}"
```

might be also

```
"{"id":1,"some_key":"GOOD"}"
```

Right now my objects is:

```
class someClass {
    int id,
    int some_key
}
```

I will have to change the some key to a String type I guess and then in the parsing check if the type is not string to convert the some_key to string? or is there a way do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make that variable dynamic in the class for parsing whatever data you recieve and when you are going to use it. You can just check it by using

```
someKey.runtimeType
```

to check the type and use by whatever way you want. 
Your class will look something like this

```
class SomeClass {
  int id;
  dynamic someKey;

  SomeClass({this.id, this.someKey});

  SomeClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    someKey = json['some_key'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['some_key'] = this.someKey;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and where you want to parse the data  use this

```
SomeClass someclass = SomeClass.fromJson(jsonDecode(<YOUR JSON STRING HERE>));
```